# JavaFX TextField листенер возвращает путь папки с проектом

Tags: javafx

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь сейчас разбираться с javaFX

Есть следующий код:

```
public void SourceFolderTextFieldMethod() {
    sourceFolderTextField.textProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        messageConsoleSourceOK(newValue);
    }));

    sourceFolderTextField.setOnAction((event -> {
        String folder = sourceFolderTextField.getCharacters().toString();
        messageConsoleSourceOK(folder);
    }));
}

public void messageConsoleSourceOK (String value) {                                                                 //Проверяем существование папки по данному пути
    File file = new File(value);
    if (file.exists()) {
        sourceCheckerCircle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        consoleOutputTextArea.appendText("The source folder is selected. Path " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " is exists\n");
    }
    else {
        sourceCheckerCircle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

Листенер при обработке значения в TextField, 
когда `newValue = "c:"` возвращает путь к папке проекта.

Если значение `"c:\"` возвращает нормальный результат, что путь `c:\` существует.

Если повторить то же самое с диском `D`, то в обоих вариантах отрабатывает нормально.

Как можно исключить некорректный возврат, и с чем это может быть связано?

Заранее благодарен за ответ

Comment: Вам не нравиться, что new File("c:/").exists() == true ?

Comment: мне не нравится, то что в варианте "C:" возвращается не "C:" или "C:\" (как в случае с другими дисками), а возвращается что-то вроде "c:\JavaProjects\Project1" т.е. папка запущенного проекта